# Access Django db by another python progra

Tags: django, postgresql, authentication, orm

I have a Django project working fine (deployed in nginx), using postgresql database.

I have to access ORM database from another python program. I'm doing this with this code:

```
if os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'WebSite.settings'):
    import django
    django.setup()
    from WebSite.operation.models import Registers, OperationMode
    from WebSite.trend.models import TrendRegister
    from django.utils import timezone
else:
    raise
    sys.exit(1)
```

When i execute the program with default user (pi is my default user), works fine, but if a execute the program in root mode, the following erro occurrs:

"password authentication failed for user root"

I must have to execute this other program in root mode. How can i resolve this?

Comment: I find it very unlikely that you need to run your program as root. The only thing that should run as root is the system itself, everything else should be a less privileged user. However Django does not use the current user to access the db, so you need to give more details about what is going on here.

Comment: I created a user called pi in postgresql and make this:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydab TO pi

My settings.py:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbdata',
        'USER:': 'pi',
        'PASSWORD': 'raspberry',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        '`PORT': '', 
    },
}

I need it's other python program run on raspbrerry starts. But i can do this only using root mode. Using "crontab - e" to default user not working.

I try all i know. I tried, crontab, configuring program as service. Nothing.

Comment: This is just a guess here, but does you `pi` user have environment variables set that are read by Django's settings for things like your database password? If so, those environment variables are unlikely to be available for the `root` user.